# Form loaded into div w/ AJAX no longer submits

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli

Let me start by apologizing for the information overload.  I have no idea what is not working, so I included a little of everything here.

I have a page named jobs.php that shows a table of open 'jobs' on the left side.  When the add job button is clicked, the form to add a new job is loaded into the div on the right side of the page using this:

```
 //Get Next Job

$query = "SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE job_id = (SELECT MAX(job_id) FROM jobs)";
$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error . __LINE__);
$topjob = $result->fetch_assoc();
$nxtjob = $topjob['job_id'] + 1;

<button class="btn btn-primary pull-right ajaxCall" id="addJobBtn" onclick="nxtJob('<?php echo $nxtjob; ?>')">Add Job</button>

function nxtJob(job) {
    var nxtjob = job;
    $("#jobDetails").html("Loading...");
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        data: {'id':nxtjob},
        url: "addjob.php",
        async: true,
        success: function(data) {
            $("#jobDetails").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

The reasoning behind the get variable is that I need the next job # to be used as a value in the form.

The form itself is on addjob.php, and the very simplified version is this:

```
<?php 
 require 'database.php';

        if (isset($_POST['addNewJob'])) {

        $error = '';

        //Check Job # for duplicate if manually changed
        $job = $_POST['addjob'];

        $query = "SELECT job_id from jobs WHERE job_id = '$job'";
        $result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error . __LINE__);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            $error .= '<br/>Job # already exists.'
        }

        if ($error == '') {
            //Set variables for insert
            $job = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['addjob']);
            $status = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['addstatus']);

            $sql = "INSERT INTO jobs (job_id, status)
        VALUES ('$job', '$status')";
            if (mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql)) {
                $validation = '< div class="alert alert-success" > Job ' . $job . ' Successfully Added </div >';
            } else {
                $validation = '<div class="alert alert-danger" > "ERROR: Could not able to execute' . $sql . mysqli_error($mysqli);
            }
        } else {
            $validation = ' <div class="alert alert - danger">Job Not Added:' . $error . '</div>';
        }
        ?>
        <form class="form - horizontal" method="post" id="addJobForm">
            <div class="form - group">
                <label for="addjob" class="col - sm - 2 control - label">Job #</label>

                <div class="col - sm - 4">
                    <input type="text" class="form - control" name="addjob"
                           value=" <?php echo $nxtjob; ?>">
                </div>
                <label for="addstatus" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Status</label>

                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <?php
                    $options = array("New", "In Progress", "Waiting for Parts", "Ready for Customer", "Completed");
                    ?>
                    <select class="form-control" name="addstatus">
                        <?php foreach ($options as $option): ?>
                            <option>
                                <?php echo $option; ?>
                            </option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" name="addNewJob" id="addNewJob" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Submit New
                Job
            </button>
        </form>

 <?php echo $validation; ?>
```

When the add job button is clicked on jobs.php (below), the form loads beautifully, but it doesn't work.

```
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <table class="table table-hover" id="jobTable" data-link="row">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="col-md-2">Job #</th>

                            <th class="col-md-4">Customer Name</th>

                            <th class="col-md-6">Description</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <?php
                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($jobs)) {
                            // Print out the contents of the entry


                            date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
                            $startdate = date("m/d/Y", strtotime($row['started']));


                            echo '<tr>';
                            echo '<td><a class="ajaxCall" href="#" rel="' . $row['job_id'] . '"></a>' . $row['job_id'] . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>' . $row['cust_name'] . '</td>';
                            echo '<td class="col-lg-2">' . $row['description'] . '</td>';
                            echo '</tr>';
                        }
                        ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div id='jobDetails'></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

When I click Submit New Job, the right side of the page simply goes blank.  The form disappears, and no new entry is created in the sql table.  However, the form works just fine if I use it directly from addjob.php.

I've read about binding after an AJAX call, and I'm guessing it has something to do with that, but I can't seem to get it working.  This is my first attempt at AJAX, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Nothing is calling your "nxtJob(job)" function

Comment: How are you submitting the form? It has no `action` attribute, so it will submit to the original page URL.

Comment: My mistake, I forgot to include the code for my button.  I edited the question to reflect it.  The button click successfully displays the form as intended by way of the nxtjob function.

Comment: @Barmar the form is submitted using the `if (isset($_POST['addNewJob'])) `

Comment: Your AJAX call doesn't send the `addNewJob` parameter, so that test will fail. The only parameter it sends is `{id: nxtjob}`.

Comment: `addjob.php` is used when you perform the AJAX call by clicking on the `Add Job` button. When you click on the `Submit New Job` button, it submits the form normally, not with AJAX. And since there's no `action="addjob.php"` in the form, it submits it to `jobs.php`.

Comment: Thanks, @Barmar .   It makes sense, and it looks like it will work if I add an action and process the form on another page.  However, I wanted it all on one page so I could use the validation shown with `$error` above and so that the entire form isn't wiped if a duplicate job # is accidentally used.  What's the best way to go about something like that?

Comment: Use AJAX to submit the form. `$("#addJobForm").submit(function() { ... }` and use AJAX inside that event handler.